# voice request and voice reply application developement

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to make a app that could help poor students to learn  good education. many villages in my country don't have proper teachers to teach new things plus teachers  English is not good  so good ! 
all i want is a app called  my teacher where  i have 6  audios files
3 of them are request files and 3 of them are reply files 
request
1)Teach numbers (audio file)
reply from mobile 
1reply)one 1 two 2 three 3 so on (audio file)
like this  i want to add on for 5 to 6 types of stories and things for small kids

i try ed a lot of examples all request internet connection .  that village don't have internet

i want them to happen in local without internet connection

and only 1 button saying  "star teacher"

The teacher request the mobile with voice request

please guide me to a good path to help the kids

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.11" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="My teacher"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="177dp"
        android:src="@drawable/start teacher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do you want a speech recolonization system which would convert input voice into text. That converted text will be further processed and proper action will be taken. Is that what you want ?

Comment: yes  correct that is what i want

Comment: `what does you tried so far`